# How can I make a pandas TimedeltaIndex act as a denominator?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to divide a pandas (0.22.0) Timedelta by a TimedeltaIndex to obtain a Float64Index of fractional values. For example:

```
>>> td_index = pd.TimedeltaIndex(['1 days', '2 days', '3 days'])
>>> td_index
TimedeltaIndex(['1 days', '2 days', '3 days'], dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq=None)
>>> td = pd.Timedelta('1D')
>>> td
Timedelta('1 days 00:00:00')
>>> td_index / td  # expected, like division
Float64Index([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype='float64')
>>> td / td_index  # unexpected, why the same as above?
Float64Index([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype='float64')
>>> td.total_seconds() / td_index.total_seconds()  # this works in a pinch
Float64Index([1.0, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333], dtype='float64'
```

It seems that the former of these, i.e., the one with the Timedelta in the denominator, can be thought of as ["frequency conversion"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#frequency-conversion), but I am unsure about why putting the index in the denominator would have the same behavior, especially when this behavior is unlike that exhibited by other indexes. For instance, this doesn't seem to apply to using Float64Index directly:

```
>>> pd.Float64Index([1, 2, 3]) / 1)
Float64Index([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype='float64')
>>> 1 / pd.Float64Index([1, 2, 3]))
Float64Index([1.0, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333], dtype='float64')  # the behavior I want
```

1. Why do pandas Timedeltas and TimedeltaIndexes act like this?
2. Is there any way to achieve float-like division with a TimedeltaIndex and Timedelta, i.e., without first converting to a different representation (like with `.total_seconds()`)?

Answer (score 1):

This only fully answers your second question.

**Why do pandas Timedeltas and TimedeltaIndexes act like this?**

You can have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timedeltas.pyx#L1080), in particular `__truediv__`, where you can see division logic for various types.

**Is there any way to achieve float-like division with a TimedeltaIndex and Timedelta?**

No. Judging from the source code, *all* comparisons, in the background, involve converting to or retrieving floats before applying division. This makes sense, as `datetime` objects are built on numeric data.

Your `timedelta` objects are stored internally in ns. For example, `td.delta` or `td.value` both return 86400000000000.

Of course, there is no reason you need to convert to seconds. `td.days / td_index.days` would also work.